# curved surface from points in 3D space with ANDROID

Tags: android, opengl-es, plot

I'm new to developing on Android and I'm trying to use OpenGL ES 1.0 on android to create a curved surface in 3D space like the one [in this picture](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14148/calculating-the-mean-curvature-of-a-surface-suggestions).

I have 16 points in a 3D space, for which the x-axis and y-axis are fixed and z-axis (height of the points on the surface) changes in time.

Could I get some hints so I can go on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Drawing such plots basically means dealing with a height map.

In general, you define a math function value(x, y) that returns height, then you draw it as a grid with even spaces between points.

```
for x = -10...10 step 1
    for z = -10...10 step 1
       addVertex(x, myHeightMap(x, z), z)
```

Here is a great resource for you I think:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Scientific_OpenGL_Tutorial_04

Simple example: http://3dengine.org/Draw_a_grid